# SendShortMessageRequest nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

I have a spring boot application and i am trying to access a SOAP webservice

```
SendShortMessageRequest request = new SendShortMessageRequest();
AddressList addressList = new AddressList();

List<Address> recipientAddresses = new ArrayList<>();

Address recipientAddress = new Address();
recipientAddress.setAddr(recipient);
recipientAddresses.add(recipientAddress);
addressList.setAddress(recipientAddresses);

Address originator = new Address();
originator.setAddr(sender);

request.setText(validationCode);
request.setRecipients(addressList);
request.setOriginator(originator);

SendShortMessageResponse response = (SendShortMessageResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
        .marshalSendAndReceive(messagesLocation, request, new SoapActionCallback(sendShortMessageAction));
```

I am getting a soap exception . any idea what is wrong with this.

```
org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.openmind.primecast.webservices.wsdl.SendShortMessageRequest nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:913)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:682)
    at org.springframework.ws.support.MarshallingUtils.marshal(MarshallingUtils.java:81)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate$2.doWithMessage(WebServiceTemplate.java:399)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:590)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
    at com.openmind.primecast.webservices.impl.PhoneNumberConfirmationMessageClientImpl.sendConfirmationMessage(PhoneNumberConfirmationMessageClientImpl.java:94)
    at com.openmind.primecast.service.UserService.setupContactNumber(UserService.java:290)
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have registered the class  SendShortMessageRequest     @XmlRegistry
it started to work then.

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {
    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link SendShortMessageRequest }
     *
     */
    public SendShortMessageRequest createSendShortMessageRequest() {
        return new SendShortMessageRequest();
    }
    
    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link SendShortMessageResponse }
     *
     */
    public SendShortMessageResponse createSendShortMessageResponse() {
        return new SendShortMessageResponse();
    }
}
```